Comment comprendre « Diamants sur canapé » ?
Je viens d’apprendre que le film américain Breakfast at Tiffany’s s’intitule en français Diamants sur canapé, quoique la traduction de la nouvelle de Truman Capote sur laquelle le film se base s’intitule Petit Déjeuner chez Tiffany.
J’ignore – et je n’ai pas encore pu trouver – une allusion qui explique la traduction du titre français du film. C’est clair que diamants fait allusion à la sophistication et au style auxquels aspire Holly Golightly, le rôle de Audrey Hepburn. Et l’intégralité du titre me suggère une référence ironique à un hors-d’œuvre, un mets. Mais je n’étais nullement convaincu qu’elle n’a pas à voir avec un meuble.
Alors, qu’est-ce qui se passe avec ce groupe nominal ? Quelle est l’image qu’il évoque ? Y-a-t-il une expression idiomatique qu’on reconnaîtrait en rencontrant ce titre ?
J’avais cherché « saumon sur canapé » et « caviar sur canapé », mais aucune des deux expressions semble particulièrement idiomatique. Puis Eurêka ? J’ai trouvé (chez Sotheby’s) une affiche originale dans laquelle Hepburn semble presqu’émerger d’un divan, d’un sofa. Okay, regardons Amazon: on y trouve plusieurs livres avec art qui inclut des sofas, y compris :

Cédric – Parasite sur canapé,
Confidences sur canapé,
Divas sur canapé,
Liberté sur canapé, et
Secrets sur canapé.

D’accord, sur canapé peut s’employer avec la signification de « assis (ou allongé) sur un [ou peut-être le] sofa ». Mais… mais on y trouve aussi Ma cuisine sur canapé dont la description nous promet « 100 recettes gourmandes pour des apéritifs dînatoires bluffants !» Est-ce que ce dernier emploi est un jeu de mots ? Ou peut-être c’est l’envers ? J’ai trouvé œufs sur canapé. Donc est-ce possible que ce sont les références aux sofas qui constituent des calembours ?

-Je pencherais plutôt pour couch, pour continuer dans l'évocation du luxe et de la séduction.

Cette question  – telle qu'elle est posée – ne peut appeler que des réponses très subjectives, elle relève de la critique de cinéma. Les diamants ce sont les bijoux et la vie luxueuse, et aussi une façon d'attirer le regard sur les yeux d'Audrey Hepburn comparés à des diamants (même derrière ses lunettes de soleil) par certains critiques qui ont parlé d'un film sur le regard.  À mon avis les canapés ça peut être aussi bien pris au sens culinaire, (les bijoux servis sans aucun effort  comme du foie gras ou du caviar sur une tranche de pain) qu'au sens du meuble (sexe).

Et bien sûr pour le sens culinaire il y aussi  la référence aux fêtes organisées par Holly, fêtes dans lesquelles on sert, entre autres, des canapés.

« un jeu de mots  » : oui, comme j'ai essayé de le dire dans mon commentaire précédent, pour moi (mais c'est subjectif) il y a un jeu de mots sur canapé (same word in English so I expected you knew what it is).  Diamants servis sur un canapé (canapé →la tranche de pain de mie ; diamants → la garniture) mais aussi diamants obtenus en s'allongeant sur un canapé en échange de faveurs sexuelles : Holly veut  épouser un homme riche pour qui elle n’éprouve pas d’amour.

@None La question est très explicite: "y a-t-il un calembour sur le mot canapé, ou une équivoque basée sur les deux sens (mobilier+culinaire)?". Toute réponse est subjective, sans pour autant être affaire d'opinion.

@None Une question d'opinion serait par exemple "ce titre est-t-il une traduction judicieuse de l'anglais?".

Il s'agit d'un euphémisme, ou d'un sous-entendu graveleux, plutôt que d'un jeu de mots proprement dit.
Les Etazuniens ont l'expression Casting Couch, que nous pouvons traduire "audition sur canapé". En France, il est sorti un film titré Promotion canapé.
Par analogie, le titre implique que les diamants sont offerts en récompense de galipettes sur canapé.

+1, même si je n'irais pas jusqu'à dire "graveleux", ce n'est pas non plus "diamants sur oreiller". "Canapé" évoque un intérieur confortable et des dîners mondains autant qu'un sous-entendu sexuel. Je pense aussi que le double sens avec l'amuse-bouche est réel (l'idée d'un diamant posé sur un canapé se comprend mieux dans ce sens-là).

@guillaume31 à chacun ses fantasmes: "canapé" m'évoque aussi un élément de mobilier saugrenu dans le luxueux bureau d'un impresario, producteur ou directeur de banque. Tout cuir et sans oreiller.
